# Avoiding 'sudo apt install' in install packages

Tags: ubuntu, installation, apt-get

I'm trying to create an install script including some extra dependencies. Is there anyway to avoid having the end user have to perform a 'sudo apt install' for the following:

> sudo apt-get install build-essential
>
> sudo apt-get install libx11-xcb-dev libglu1-mesa-dev
>
> sudo apt-get install libwebkitgtk-dev
>
> sudo apt-get install gnome-shell-extension-top-icons-plus
>
> sudo apt install gnome-tweak-tool

How can I find the corresponding tar files to include in the package so the user does not have to perform 'sudo apt-get'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to add them to the script and then clear the log like so:

```sh
sudo apt update
sudo apt install build-essential libx11-xcb-dev libglu1-mesa-dev libwebkitgtk-dev gnome-shell-extension-top-icons-plus gnome-tweak-tool -y
clear
```

Or you can manually download and the packages and copy all of the files to a ./bin folder and instead of running the command directly `build` for example you can run `./bin/build`.

Comment: You should've carefully using the -y flags on systems you didn't configure, it could update other dependencies  that may result in a broken system or applications. Not everyone is running with an stable system, and not everyone uses applications from the repositories only.